# How to determine the caller of a before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a before_action that is called for user authentication and other features. But there is some functionality in the before_action that depends on the caller.
I don't want to separate the logic into two before_actions and use a skip_before_action; as large parts of the before_action must be executed in any case.

How can I determine the calling controller and method of the before_action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think that a caller of a before_action is that action? This is not so. But, perhaps, you *do* need to find the caller. In this case, use `caller`. It'll return you a stack trace, which you can filter as you wish.

To find the action, use `params[:action]`.

Comment: Oh, I was going around in circles trying to figure this out, sometimes it is as simple as that; I totally forgot about params. It does all I need, there is the controller as well as the action available. Thanks.